# replace output of lines through external command

Tags: shell, vim, pipe

Suppose I have several lines of python code:

```
for i in range(10):
    print "item {}".format(i)
```

is there a way I can get the output of the lines directly in vim without having to copy the text into the interpreter and copy the output back?

The lines are usually just a part of the file, not the hole file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The real answer (the others were close)

Do a visual selection then

```
:'<,'>!python -
```

(quickest way: <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>!</kbd>`python -`<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do `:read !python myscript.py` and get the output pasted into your current buffer. This [vim wikia entry](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Capture_ex_command_output) provides more info.

Comment: thanks, but this implies saving the file, I would like to know if it is possible to do this with just part of the file

Comment: the technique used in this question might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230266/vi-vim-how-to-pipe-visually-selected-text-to-a-unix-command-and-append-output-to ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`:w !python -`

That should execute the entire file by itself, or just a selection if you have something highlighted.